OpenSSL CVE-2022-1292
Our vulnerability scanner found an old version of openssl v1.0.2zd that seems to be still installed on our server however when I do the version check it's showing the latest (according to the repo) - v1.1.1f.
The path of the active openssl is /usr/bin/openssl and the one that has the vulnerability on is in /opt/omni/bin/openssl.
Anyone Can guide me on how can I remove? please
Thanks.
Edit #1, sorry forgot to mention:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal


screenshot

Do dpkg -S /opt/omni/bin/openssl to find which package provides that file. Then decide whether you want to uninstall that package.

You've not provided your OS/release, as https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-1292 shows the packages that contain the fix, or systems that are not impacted.

@Jos dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /opt/omni/bin/openssl

Your details now highlight that the machine in unmaintained thus your issue.. Your current details show you've not applied security fixes since 2022-August if not for longer (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO relate date of 22.04.5, but installed systems upgraded to it BEFORE that date!!).   Apply security fixes asap if your machine is used on a network on online, and address your system management.

How did openssl v1.0.2zd get installed in the first place? This isn't an official Ubuntu version of this library.

Does this answer your question? How to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS?

@ArturMeinild fresh iso installation from ubuntu - the server was installed several years ago, nothing custom.

@guiverc Do you know how to fix it? os upgrade?

Just apply normal upgrades.. sudo apt update will update your machines software lists (so it's aware of what upgraded packages & security fixes are available), then to apply them use apt upgrade or if required apt full-upgrade  (apt-get dist-upgrade is equivalent)... if upgrade or full-upgrade | dist-upgrade is required will depend on what changes you've made to your system; esp. 3rd party packages...   20.04 system upgraded to 20.04.5 back in late-August 2022, currently report themselves as 20.04.6

@guiverc thanks

Key is the fix for the CVE you mention (see prior comment & link I provided; which points to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/3.0.2-0ubuntu1.1) has the mitigation or fix for that CVE..   Your details highlight you've not been applying fixes (ie. still 20.04.4 !!!) thus not have the security fixes you've not yet applied is expected. Upgrade your system regularly; or have them auto-update.  You've likely modified your system & put holds on upgrades for some reason, or could be using a Ubuntu based system (not Ubuntu) thus aren't applying all fixes, but 20.04 has fixed that CVE!

I don't believe you. I believe the files /opt/omni/bin are a part of Omniback / Data Protector solution, which is NOT default. See here for reference

/opt is an empty directory on a clean Ubuntu install.. Whatever is in it was added post-install, OR you're not using an official Ubuntu product (Ubuntu based for example) which has been modified & other stuff has been added (many based systems include software from non-Ubuntu sources too).  Your 20.04.4 detail implies you've either not been applying security fixes for a very long time OR you aren't using Ubuntu at all (maybe a Ubuntu based system that was based on the 2022-February 20.04 system (20.04.4))

@ArturMeinild hmm data protector is used for the backups, will check with the systems guys about this - didn't know that it creates that directory. Thanks

It's Data Protector that has installed the invalid openssl library, so it needs to be sorted that way around.

Thanks for your help @ArturMeinild and all the others who have contributed :)
